# CMake: Static library with multiple projects

Tags: cmake

I have two projects using CMake. Project A build a static library that is then linked to project B. The problem is, when I change a source file from project A and build both projects, project B won't automatically be linked again. How can I add the output from project A (the static library) to project B?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of my problem:

ProjectA CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(PROJECTA)

ADD_LIBRARY(projectA STATIC "src/foo.cpp")
```

ProjectB CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(PROJECTB)

set(PROJECTA_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../ProjectA)
include_directories(${PROJECTA_DIR}/include)

link_directories(${PROJECTA_DIR}/build)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(projectB "src/main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(projectB projectA)
```

To reproduce the problem:

1. Build both projects (ProjectA needs to be built first).
2. Change ProjectA/src/foo.cpp
3. Build ProjectA (it will update libProject.a)
4. Build ProjectB (it *won't* link the executable with the new libProject.a, instead it will assume that no changes were made and do nothing).

Comment: Can you show the CMakeList(s) involved?

Comment: Angew: I add an example to my question.

Comment: Are these CMakeLists totally standalone, or are they both subdirectories of one "parent" CMakeList?

Comment: Angew: They are totally standalone.

Comment: The "native" CMake way would be to make them aware of each other's targets, by making them (logical) subdirectories of a common parent. (Note that this doesn't necessarily imply a subdirectory relationship on disk). If that cannot be applied in your case, you could look into CMake's [ExternalProject](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject) module.

Comment: You could also try removing `link_directories()` (which is pretty much deprecated) and using the full path in `target_link_libraries()`. It might help, not sure.

Comment: Angew: Removing link_directories() and using full path in target_link_libraries() did the trick, thank you. You should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer.

Normally, when CMake projects have to cooperate, it's beneficial to make them part of the same buildsystem using `add_subdirectory()`. That way, CMake can track dependency between their targets, automatically resolve references to logical target names etc.

If that is not an option for you, you should at least remove `link_directories()` and instead use the full path to the library in `target_link_libraries()`. Use of `link_directories()` is generally discouraged, it's known to cause issues.